# Use Interface property to update progress bar view model

Tags: c#, wpf

Here's the code what I have:

```
    namespace ns1
    Class A()
    {
        //set interface prop value
        _progressBarListner.CurrCount =2;
        _progressBarListner.TotalCount =5;
    }

    Interface IProgressBarListner
    {
        int CurrCount {get;set;}
        int TotalCount {get;set;}
    }

    public class ProgBarViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        // binded variable to a label on progress bar
        public string ProgressPercentage
            {
                get => _progressPercentage;
                set => SetProperty(ref _progressPercentage, value);
            }

        // binded variable to value attribute of progress bar
        public double ProgressValue
        {
            get => _progressValue;
            set => SetProperty(ref _progressValue, value);
        }  

        //Instead of using this event handler, I would like to consume interface property to set 

          private void UpdateProgressBar(UpdateProgressBarArgs args)
            {                
                var percentCompleted = (args.CurrentCount / args.TotalCount) * 100;
                ProgressValue = percentCompleted;
                ProgressPercentage = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0} %", percentCompleted.ToString("0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));            
            }
    }
```

Currently, it subscribe to an event and update the progress bar view model properties. Instead I want to consume this interface property to update progress bar view model. How can I achieve the same?

Comment: Just use the Progress pattern from Microsoft by using the [IProgress interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iprogress-1?view=netframework-4.8), which via the [Progress implementation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.progress-1?view=netframework-4.8) also takes care of dispatching the progress to the UI thread in case you do your work in other threads/tasks. For an example on how to use it see https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/async-in-4-5-enabling-progress-and-cancellation-in-async-apis/ - just ignore the async stuff there if you don't need it.

Comment: @ckuri If you ignore the async stuff, the screen won't update. You need to return control back to the dispatcher to allow it to redraw your screen.